# How to scheduled a tweet using twit package in twitter in Javascript

Tags: node.js, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to schedule a tweet using [twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit) package in node.js, but not able to get a proper idea on how to implement it. I went through the Twitter API documentation also [twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/creatives/api-reference/scheduled-tweets#post-accounts-account-id-scheduled-tweets) 
It is using `account_id`  and `as_user_id` as parameter how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

- First I made a function to tweet something:

```
function tweetThis(txt) {
  // text in the tweet to be posted
  var tweet = {
    status: txt
  };

  // posting tweet
  T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

  // callback function to post method
  function tweeted(err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Something went wrong :(');
    } else {
      console.log('Yay it worked :)');
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the function `tweetThis()` has a callback function, `tweeted()`. The callback function is called by the `.post` method. Now I can use this code to tweet something, for example:

```
tweetThis('This is an example');
```

Would result in a tweet containg that text. At the terminal, you would see the message "Yay it worked (:".

- Now to schedule a tweet we can use the `setInterval()` method:

This method takes as arguments a function to execute (in this case, `tweetThis()`) and an amount of time (in ms) to wait before executing it. So to wait 30 seconds before tweeting:

```
setInterval(tweetThis('This is a scheduled tweet'), 1000 * 30);
```

Now it will wait 30000ms (AKA 3s) and then call the function `tweetThis()`, which will tweet the string argument the output in the console can confirm if it all worked out.

PS: I based this on this series of videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6atTSxoRiVnSuOn6JHnq2yV . It is a great playlist and I'm halfway through it. Some things are a bit different because the videos are from 2017 but mostly it's all the same. So if you have any doubts, the video "15.5: Scheduling Tweets Using setInterval() - Twitter Bot Tutorial" may help you :D

PS2: I just realized some videos are from 2015 and others from 2017. And that the Twit npm package is deprecated, as some functionalities don't work anymore. It generally works but it's not up to date with the Twitter API. I recommend the Twitter Lite package: https://github.com/draftbit/twitter-lite which I didn't start using yet but intend to.